# Facing issue while solving this pattern problem

Tags: python, design-patterns

Given an integer N, print the corresponding pattern for N.

For example if N = 5 then pattern will be like:

*___*
*___*
*___*
*___*
*___*

This is my code:

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(1,n+1):
    if n > 2:
        for j in range(1,n+1,n-2):
            print("*",end = "")       
    else:
        for j in range(1,n+1):
            if j <= i:
                print("*",end = "")`enter code here`
            else:
                print("*", end = "")    
     print()

enter code here
```

Comment: Need Solution:
n = 5
first and last character * and "_" in spaces

Comment: Pattern using underscores or * sign ?

Comment: ```print('_'*n)``` will print _____

Comment: The sample output doesn't seem to align with your stated requirement. Please show what output you would expect for some given *n*

Comment: @MayurPawar please clarify your question

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
n = int(input())

for x in range(n):
    print('_',end=' ',flush=True)
```